# Challah dough that loses its amount

Tags: halacha, blessing, mistakes, shiurim-measurements, separating-challah

A theoretical question: 
Someone was making a dough and in the process a large piece fell out from the mixture onto the floor. They had made exactly the right amount in order to take challah with a bracha. The part that fell onto the floor they now no longer want to use as part of the dough. Therefore the mixture is now missing a proper "shiur" (amount) in order to take challah with a bracha. Can a bracha still be made when challah is taken from the dough in such a case?

To begin with one could ask, when does the dough become chiyuv in general in taking off challah? Does it help in this case that the piece of dough is still around and can be put together with the entire mixture, then separate the challah with a bracha, even though the person will not use this piece and throw it away. Would it make a difference if the piece of dough that fell off was no longer around at all?

Answer (score 1):

See Maseches Challah Perek 3:1 and Shulchan Aruch Yore Dei'ah 327:2 that the obligation begins when the flour and water are mixed well together. Therefore, if at the time that the large piece fell out from the mixture onto the floor they were mixed, it still has the obligation and requires a Beracha. This is no worse than when one forgets to separate Challah before Shabbos (in the diaspora) he may eat from the bread and leave over some bread and separates Challah after Shabbos with a Beracha even though at the time of separation he has less than the amount of dough/bread that requires Challah to be taken.

In Israel one may not eat any of the bread before Separating Challah.

Comment: What about the din that if one is going to split up the challah and give it to a number of people. I know over there there is a discussion in regards to if a bracha is made when there is a shiur, not a shiur, many cases, etc.

Comment: There it was his original intent, here it was not.

Comment: you're right. If I made a dough and then decided after it was already made to separate it, do I still make a bracha? Mistama yes since it was made al manas that I would keep the whole thing. Only afterwards did I think to give it away.